# I have Eclipse 3.5.2 on my 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10 box, but I cannot use Eclipse install new software

Tags: installation, 10.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.  I installed Eclipse via the

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt
```

I ended up with Eclipse 3.5.2.  It works like a charm.  But there was no adb.  So I went to Help->Install new Software and it let's me choose the Galileo update site.  But when I use it, it just says "No Repository found".

My immediate goal is to install ADB.  But I'd like to install the entire ADT and I'd like "Install New Software..." in my Eclipse in general to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer the case if you install from repository.  Tested on 12.04 LTS Beta.

Install Eclipse from repository.
Install the CDT plugin through the Help install software menu.
`sudo apt-get install ia32libs`
Install the ADT plugin through the Help install software menu.  With [this](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) link.
Choose to install the SDKs during the ADT install.
  [image]